# Python: program called from another file not running correctly

Tags: python, import, filesystems, directory

Among the bugs I have found and solved so far, my actual code is pretty clean and runs good.  I think I have narrowed down a problem I am having to the following... I have a folder, "Stocks", that contains python code and another nested folder, "PullStock", with more python code and text files within it.

Filesystem example:

```
Folder: Stocks
  python code files (`stockcalc.py`)
  Folder: PullStock
    python code files (`pullList.py`)
    text files
```

I can run the program `pullList.py` by itself and it runs fine.  All it does is parse lines of a text file and store the variables into an array.  The output when I run this program alone is provided below:

```
array length in pullList:  2
```

Now when I run `stockcalc.py`, I import the file `pullList.py` from the folder 'PullStock' and it does not run the same.  The output is below:

```
array length in pullList:  0
```

My header of `stockcalc.py` looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from PullStock import pullList
#import PullStock.pullList
```

I have tried both of these solutions above in my header and neither of them seems to work.  If I am calling the file, then shouldn't it run the same as when I run it by itself?  If a solution can not be figured out from the above information, then I am sorry for wasting your time and I have so more work to do.

Answer (score 0):

You've got at least multiple problems. Start here:

```
from StockList import pullList
```

Your directory is called `PullStock`, but you're trying to use the name `StockList`. That's obviously not going to work.

But, even if you fix that, you've got a bigger problem: `StockList` is not a package. In Python 2 (which it looks like you're using), a directory is only a package if it has a file named `__init__.py` in it. It can be empty, but it has to exist.

It's almost always wrong to run a script inside a package directory, so by fixing that, you're also breaking the part that worked. You may get away with it anyway, but you should look into a better organization—e.g., a `__main__.py` file that lets you run the package as a script, or a "launcher" script at the top level.

I'd lay 50/50 odds that you have one more problem: if `pullList.py` is opening `'spam.txt'` and `'eggs.txt'` and just expecting that to work, it won't work when your working directory isn't the script's directory; you'll want to add `scriptdir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0]))` to the top of the script, and then use `os.path.join(scriptdir, 'spam.txt')`, etc.

And finally, it's usually a good idea to use all-lowercase names for your modules. Especially if you want the same code to run on both Windows and non-Windows systems.

Comment: Ah my bad, I edited the import above... That was supposed to be `from PullStock import pullList`. Anyway, I am running python3.4. SO, are you saying I must implement those lines of code into my `stockcalc.py` or the `pullList.py`?

Comment: @young_buffet: First, if you're using 3.4, you should probably have `#!/usr/bin/env python3`, not `#!/usr/bin/env python` (unless you're on Arch Linux, which I'm pretty sure you're not). Meanwhile, I don't know what you mean by "implement those lines of code into…".

Comment: First off, thank you for the extra tips.  I am learning many things right now from you.. I am running ubuntu 12.04. And I meant the `scriptdir = ...` lines of code.  What file, based on my filesystem listed above, should I implement those lines into?  Or what is another solution to the problem I am facing?

Comment: Exactly what you put in `scriptdir` and where you put it depends on your code, and how you've chosen to deal with the previous problem, and so on. Do you understand what a current working directory is, and have you read the docs on `abspath`, `dirpath`, and `argv` to understand what they're doing? If so, it should be pretty easy to figure out what you need for your code.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to work with multiple file organization and creating packages and importing modules, you should have a look at the tutorial in Python Doc. https://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/modules.html#packages

There you will find a good explanation of how you should organize your packages and what you need to add as file(**__init__.py**) to make that folder recognized as a module...etc.